# jquery RegExp is not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, regex

what is wrong, as explained by an example:

```
form = 'some other [1][2] data ... data[Company][c_list][2][name_2] ... some other data';
form.replace(new RegExp('[c_list][2]', 'g'), '[c_list][1]');
```

get: `data[Company][c_list][2][name[c_list][1]]`

need: `data[Company][c_list][1][name_2]`

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: I see no jquery here, just good old Javascript.

Comment: This is vanilla Javascript.

Comment: there is nothing called jquery regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters `[`and `]` are used to make a set, so `[c_list]` in the regular expression doesn't match the character sequence `[c_list]`, it matches one character which is `c`, `_`, `l`, `i`, `s` or `t`.

Escape the characters `[` and `]` in the expression. As you are writing the pattern as a string, you need to use `\\` to put `\` in the pattern:

```
form.replace(new RegExp('\\[c_list\\]\\[2\\]', 'g'), '[c_list][1]');
```

You can also write the regular expression as a literal, then you use just `\` to escape characters:

```
form.replace(/\[c_list\]\[2\]/g, '[c_list][1]');
```

Answer (score 1):

In a regular expression `[...]` has a special meaning of defining a character class. I think you are looking for

```
form.replace(new RegExp('\[c_list\]\[2\]', 'g'), '[c_list][1]');
```

where the brackets have been escaped.

Comment: A single backslash escapes the character in the string. You need to use `\\\` to put a backslash in the string so that the character is escaped in the pattern.

Comment: Yes, I never use `new RegExp()` myself so didn't realize that until I saw your answer, which I upvoted. Quick meta question since you are a 217k SO ninja: ahould I correct my answer, giving credit to your answer, or should I remove my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the brackets of your regexp.